# Cannot add a plugin customization to an Eclipse product built with Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, product, preferences, tycho

I'm building an Eclipse RCP product with Maven/Tycho and need to make it load a `plugin_customization.ini` file with certain product preferences and cannot achieve this.

## What I've tried

### Launch arguments

I've added `-pluginCustomization` to the launch arguments of the product. This works with a local path to the `plugin_customization.ini` file. However, in the final product the `plugin_customization.ini` file is contained in a bundle, but I cannot access that. A URI with the `platform:/plugin/` suffix does not work.

### `config.ini`

Adding the same as value of the `eclipse.pluginCustomization` key to the generated `config.ini` of the product has the same problem. It can access the local file, but not the one in a product bundle.

I couldn't figure out any possibility to add the `plugin_customization.ini` directly to the product outside of any bundle jar.

### `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension

According to the docs you can pass a `plugin_customization.ini` as value of the `preferenceCustomization` property of a `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension in a product plugin. Also without success.

## What I didn't try yet

Instead of loading a `plugin_customization.ini` I may add a bundle with an activator that sets the required preferences on startup. That seems to be some overkill, because there are the above means of setting preferences. However, that will be my last resort.

## Questions

1. Is it possible to add a file (`plugin_customization.ini` in this case) to an Eclipse product outside of a jar? How?
2. Does the `platform:/plugin/` URI in principle work with launch arguments or in a `config.ini` or is there an alternative to access a file in a bundle?
3. What else can I try?

## Versions

- Eclipse: 2022-03
- Maven: 3.6.3
- Platform: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Instead of using the command line argument `-pluginCustomization`, your Eclipse RCP product should have a plugin that does the branding and customization of your product via the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/db62206f99830a6de3e82418827cd2231a69200b/org.idealized.customization/plugin.xml#L33-L35).

Comment: @howlger As I said I tried this as well without success. However, thanks for your link, so I do now have a working example to compare with.

Comment: Make sure you do this for the application that is used by your product: [this](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/db62206f99830a6de3e82418827cd2231a69200b/org.idealized.customization/plugin.xml#L10) is [used by the product here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/db62206f99830a6de3e82418827cd2231a69200b/product/idealized.product#L4) (both with `application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench"`).

Comment: That was definitely one of my mistakes, you helped me to find, but fixing that was not sufficient. I will try to build your project to see if it works in general on my host setup.

Comment: @howlger For my other mistake see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing my project with the [project](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized) mentioned in @howlger's comment to the question, I found out why my third attempt with the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension didn't work.

To connect the product definition in the `.product` file with the product extension in an Eclipse plugin you have to ensure two things (which I did both wrong):

- The *Application* class in the product definition has to be the same as the *application* entry in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension setup (as @howlger already pointed out).
- The *Product* in the product definition (of the `.product` editor) has to point to the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension of the plugin. To achieve
  that, the *Product* value must have the format `<plugin ID>.<extension ID>`. This is stored as `id` attribute of the `product` tag in the `.product` file.